# Which one is easy to implement for starters Ehcache or Memcached?

Tags: caching, memcached, ehcache

Hi all am fresher to the coding field having background about c, c++, php, little java. I wanted to implement caching concept in my grais application (Which is my first grails experience). Can anyone suggest me, (in implementation side) which one will be easy to understand and implement for freshers like me. Your valuable answers will be very helpful for most of the freshers like me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise Ehcache is very fast than memcached.. But ehcache needs to be implemented on each slave nodes. When the size of the databse is not too large you can go for ehcache.. In implimentation side both are not too complicated to implement.